# ACF not returning image

Tags: php, wordpress, image, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to use ACF to put an image on one of my template pages.  I did a var_dump of my variable and the data is there.  Why is my image not showing up?  I tried wrapping it in an  tag but that didn't return anything.  Any suggestions?

```
  <?php
    $first_img = get_field('image_first');
    ?>
    <div class="panel--standard">
        <div class="container container__grid">
            <div class="container__col">
                <h2><?php echo get_field("heading_first"); ?></h2>
               <div>
               <?php echo get_field($first_img['url']); ?>
               </div> 
               <!-- <p><?php var_dump($first_img['url'])?></p> -->
    

            </div>

            <div class="container container__col">
                <p><?php echo get_field("content_first"); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced Custom Fields can be set to return data in a few ways. It looks by your code like this image field is set to return 'Array'. So the way you're grabbing it, $first_img is an array of your data, with URL being the source of the original, uncropped image. What you actually have isn't an 'image' itself - just the data.

On this line, you're trying to REFETCH the field data, with the URL which isn't correct:

```
<?php echo get_field($first_img['url']); ?>
```

Instead, what you're looking for is something like:

```
<img src="<?php echo $first_img['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $first_img['alt']; ?>"/>
```